# constUIScrollView doesn't work after changing constraints

Tags: swift

My UIScrollView stopped working after I added rotation dependent constraints. I put two sets of constraints in two arrays and after every rotation happens I activate one of them and deactivate the second one. It worked before the constraints were activated immediately (constraint.isActive = true), and there were only one set.

```
func setupLayout() {
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1450980392, green: 0.1960784314, blue: 0.2509803922, alpha: 1)
    setViewBackground()

    let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.addSubview(topLeftViewContainer)
    topLeftViewContainer.addSubview(idTextField)
    topLeftViewContainer.addSubview(passTextField)
    contentView.addSubview(bottomRightViewContainer)
    bottomRightViewContainer.addSubview(logInButton)
    bottomRightViewContainer.addSubview(registerButton)
    // MARK: - Portrait Constraints -

    //scrollView
    portraitConstraints.append(scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor))
    scrollVievBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: guide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    portraitConstraints.append(scrollVievBottomConstraint)
    portraitConstraints.append(scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor))

    //contentView
    portraitConstraints.append(contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor))

    //topLeftViewContainer
    portraitConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5))
    portraitConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor))

    //idTextField
    portraitConstraints.append(idTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20))
    portraitConstraints.append(idTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180))
    portraitConstraints.append(idTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.topAnchor, constant: 50))
    portraitConstraints.append(idTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    //passTextField
    portraitConstraints.append(passTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20))
    portraitConstraints.append(passTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180))
    portraitConstraints.append(passTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: idTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20))
    portraitConstraints.append(passTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    //bottomRightViewContainer
    portraitConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5))
    portraitConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.bottomAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor))
    portraitConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor))

    //logInButton
    portraitConstraints.append(logInButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30))
    portraitConstraints.append(logInButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120))
    portraitConstraints.append(logInButton.topAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomRightViewContainer.topAnchor, constant: 50))
    portraitConstraints.append(logInButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomRightViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    //registerButton
    portraitConstraints.append(registerButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30))
    portraitConstraints.append(registerButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120))
    portraitConstraints.append(registerButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logInButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 20))
    portraitConstraints.append(registerButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomRightViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    // MARK: - Landscape Constraints -

    //scrollView
    landscapeConstraints.append(scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor))
    scrollVievBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: guide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    landscapeConstraints.append(scrollVievBottomConstraint)
    landscapeConstraints.append(scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor))

    //contentView
    landscapeConstraints.append(contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor))

    //topLeftViewContainer
    landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5))
    landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor))

    //idTextField
    landscapeConstraints.append(idTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20))
    landscapeConstraints.append(idTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180))
    landscapeConstraints.append(idTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.centerYAnchor, constant: -30))
    landscapeConstraints.append(idTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    //passTextField
    landscapeConstraints.append(passTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20))
    landscapeConstraints.append(passTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180))
    landscapeConstraints.append(passTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: idTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20))
    landscapeConstraints.append(passTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    //bottomRightViewContainer
    landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5))
    landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor))
    landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor))

    //logInButton
    landscapeConstraints.append(logInButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30))
    landscapeConstraints.append(logInButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120))
    landscapeConstraints.append(logInButton.topAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomRightViewContainer.centerYAnchor, constant: -30))
    landscapeConstraints.append(logInButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomRightViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    //registerButton
    landscapeConstraints.append(registerButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30))
    landscapeConstraints.append(registerButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120))
    landscapeConstraints.append(registerButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logInButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 20))
    landscapeConstraints.append(registerButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomRightViewContainer.centerXAnchor))

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstraints)
}


// MARK: - Keyboard Handling

@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    scrollVievBottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardHeight
    scrollView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    print("SHOW KEYBOARD")
}
@objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    scrollVievBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    scrollView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    print("HIDE KEYBOARD")
}

// MARK: - Orientation -

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(portraitConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(landscapeConstraints)
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(landscapeConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstraints)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe problems come from this lines:

```
//topLeftViewContainer
landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor))
landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5))
landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor))
landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor))
```

guide.bottomAnchor or contentView.bottomAnchor?

//bottomRightViewContainer

```
landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5))
landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor))
landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor))
landscapeConstraints.append(bottomRightViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor))
```

guide.widthAnchor and guide.bottomAnchor or contentView.widthAnchor and contentView.bottomAnchor?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've changed some part of my code and now scroll works but only in portrait mode. It seems that content view is visible in both orientations but in landscape one it doesn't scroll.

Comment: My scrollView just doesn't want to resize in landscape mode. Its bottomAnchor should resize like it does in portrait orientation.

Comment: @jakubradzikowski97 landscapeConstraints.append(topLeftViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor))

It should be guide.bottomAnchor or contentView.bottomAnchor?

Comment: @jakubradzikowski97 I have updated the answer, maybe it will help.

Comment: after changing some of the constraints you mentioned, my landscape mode still doesn't let me scroll, but when keyboard shows up it just gets a bit shorter so I can see all the buttons and fields :) it looks good. I'll try to unable the scrollbar but still your answer led me to improvement! Thank you, you are the best